# How to reference grid to ActiveForm

Tags: yii2, master-detail

You have on one page ActiveForm as master record, and grid as child records, how can i make relation between them. At create time there isn't id of master record! Any advice is wellcome! TIA. Asim

Comment: Not quite clear. Please give more information and/or any code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use modal in order to add the child object. You can do it in one form. If you use a modal, you'll need to create the parent object first, and then  allow this modal to be shown. In this way, your worries will be invalid.

If you want to add a parent and a child in one form, you can pass both objects to the view and then put their fields in the form. Then on form submit, you validate both objects, and then if everything is fine, save the parent, and then the child, assigning the parent id to the child. You can do this in a transaction so that if the child fails, the parent won't be recorded as well or vise versa.

Here is some code:

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function actionSomething()
    {
        $parent = new Parent();
        $child = new Child();

        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        if ($parent->load($request->post('Parent')) && $child->load($request->post('Child'))) {
            // Do validation and if everything is fine, then save the fields
            Yii::$app->db->transaction(function() {
                $parent->save(false);

                $child->parent_id = $parent->id;
                $child->save(false);
            });
        }
        return $this->render('view', compact('parent', 'child'));
    }
}
```

The view:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>

    <?= $form->field($parent, 'fieldA') ?>
    <?= $form->field($parent, 'fieldB') ?>
    <?= $form->field($child, 'fieldA') ?>
    <?= $form->field($child, 'fieldB') ?>

...other input fields...

<?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Did you get the idea? If you have questions or problems, please ask. Here is another example. This is with an update, but the idea is the same:

[Getting Data for Multiple Models](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-multiple-models.html)

Comment: Thanks ntraykov! But what if  I have 100 child records! What scenario is in this situation? Tabular input is not good for my usage. TIA. Asim

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to acheive. You didn't say 'multiple' children. If you want to put multiple children, then create the parent first, and then add the children in another operation. For example you can create a parent page where only parents are added, and then children's page, where only children are added. Another approach would be to use ajax. You have the parent created, and then you have a button, when you push this button, a child form appends. If you push 'n' times, 'n' children forms appear...

Comment: If you insist, you can put the paren and the children to one form. Using Javascript, you can add multiple number of children and then send the whole form to the server...

Comment: ntarykov, go back to my first post: what will be dataProvider? Is it same and where is ad relation between parent and child? In that case what will be with grid when there isn't child record (new parent record and there isn't id)

Comment: Let me summarize - you have one active form that has one parent and 'n' children, which are printed as a grid view? If so, how do you create/update them?

Comment: nraykov, Yes. On one page are ActiveForm for parent, and grid for n children record. grid is used just to show children records. Modal form for adding child record is used.

Comment: Then how are you going to create the parent, since you will add children by using modals? There is a way, but it is strange...You can fill the parent's form, then by using a modal dialog you can append children to the grid view. Below each row you can put hidden inputs for each children's fields. Then you submit everything, save the parent, and then the children. What do you think about that?

Comment: Yes, that is my wishes! But how to do it? What is dataProvider for  ActiveForm and for Grid ? How can I ad child records to grid but not to db??? Please more information!!! TIA.  Asim